# Calendar or Agenda plugin for Grails

Tags: grails

I need to find a way to detect if any given person is available in a given time... but it needs to be accurate, i will explain with an example:

I have a system that allows to a given person to register, and be contacted to work in a work-by-hour job. So, a given person can be hired to work from 09:00AM to 13:00, and be hired by a completely different person to work from 16:00 to 20:00 (for example). I need a Calendar/Agenda-like plugin to grails that allow me to get the data in a given day, and hourly-accurate

Anybody knows any plugin that dows that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a plugin to my knowledge that is going to give you exactly what you need.  There is, however, a very nice jQuery plugin called [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) that I've used to implement Google Calendar like functionality for a client.

There is also a [Grails plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/full-calendar) for it, although I generally don't use plugins for JavaScript libraries.  Makes it more difficult to customize things.

You're still going to have to manage your agenda/event data yourself.  But once you have the data, feeding it to [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) via JSON is cake.

Answer (score 0):

This can be also implemented with DHTMLX JavaPlanner, check out this tutorial
http://javaplanner.com/docs/using_javaplanner_with_the_grails_framework.html